# JQuery inArray returning true

Tags: jquery, arrays

```
var arr = [ "One", "Two", "Three" ];

$('select[name="class"]').change(function() {
    if (jQuery.inArray("blah blah", arr)) {
        alert("OK");
    }
});
```

this is alerting "OK", yet "blah blah" isn't in the array... what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `jQuery.inArray` function always returns a value:

> Description: Search for a specified value within an array and return
>   its index (or -1 if not found).

Docs: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/

Change your code to:

```
if (jQuery.inArray('blah blah', arr)) >= 0) {
    alert('Ok');
}
```

Answer (score 3):

try :

```
if (jQuery.inArray("blah blah", arr) >-1) {
```

instead of :

```
if (jQuery.inArray("blah blah", arr)) {
```

Answer (score 3):

jQuery.inArray returns -1 if the item is not found. Unfortunately, -1 is a truthy value in JavaScript.

Check for -1 and you're good.